# drupal 7 module js ajax get file path

Tags: ajax, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-ajax

i have one module: wego, and i want to use ajax in wego.js which is located in wego/js/wego.js. The ajax needs send get request to get_data.php which is located in wego/get_data.php. My server setting is test.drupal.com. Here is my code:

```
jQuery(function() {
    var $basepath = Drupal.settings.basePath;
    //alert($basepath); outputs '/'
    jQuery.get($basepath+'wego/get_search_id.php',function(data){
      alert(data);
    });
});
```

and i add this js file in wego.module:

```
function wego_init() {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'wego') . '/js/wego.js');
}
```

Does anyone know why the get_search_id.php can not be found? The error message is:

```
http://test.drupal.com/wego/get_search_id.php can not be found
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you missed the forward slash after Drupal.settings.basePath in jQuery.get

It should be likes this

```
jQuery.get($basepath + '/wego/get_search_id.php',function(data){
   alert(data);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it still does not work after i add the forward slash. The error is: GET http://wego/get_search_id.php